# How to force store(overwrite) in HDFS using Mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

How do i overwrite the existing output  in HDFS with Mapreduce program.

In Pig there is statement called

```
rmf /user/cloudera/outputfiles/citycount
STORE rel into '/user/cloudera/outputfiles/citycount';
```

Similarly is there any way to achieve the same in mapreduce program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like this in your driver module.

```
 conf = new Configuration();

 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

 String pathin = args[0];
 String pathout = args[1];

 fs.delete(new Path(pathout), true);


 // it will delete the output folder if the folder already exists.
```